# Export pip packages

Tags: python, pip

I have a project with multiple dependencies installed using virtualenv and pip. I want to run my project on a server which does not have pip installed. Unfortunately, installing pip is not an option.

Is there a way to export my required packages and bundle them with my project? What is the common approach in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twitter uses [`pex`](https://pex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) files to bundle Python code with its dependencies. This will produce a single file. Another relevant tool is [`platter`](http://platter.pocoo.org/dev/) which also aims to reduce the complexity of deploying Python code to a server.

Another alternative is to write a tool yourself which creates a zip file with the Python and dependencies and unzips it in the right location on the server.

In Python 3.5 the module [`zipapp`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/zipapp.html) was introduced to improve support for this way of deploying / using code. This allows you to manage the creation of zip files containing Python code and run them directly using the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

@Simeon Visser's answer is a good way to deal with that. Mine is to build my python project with `buildout`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be outside of scope of the question, but if your need is deploying applications to servers with their dependencies, have a look at virtualization and linux containers.

It is by far the most used solution to this problem, and will work with any type of application (python or not), and it is lightweight (the performance hit of LXC is not noticeable in most cases, and isolating apps is a GREAT feature).

Docker containers, besides being trendy right now, are a very convenient way to deploy applications without caring about dependencies, etc...

The same goes for development envs with vagrant.